# General SQL/Oracle Design Question - How would you associate 2 column values to only a single primary key column?

Tags: sql, oracle

Say I have Table with the following structure and sample data

```
ID   Name  LastName

a    jim   bob
b    bob   jim
c    phil  chris
```

So, in this example I only want the column `ID` to be the Primary Key.

However, at the same time I do NOT want this type of data to be able to be stored in the table at the same time

```
ID   Name  LastName

d    jim   bob
e    bob   jim
f    phil  chris
```

The combination of Name & Last Name should only be associated to 1 primary key but, they should not be part of that key. Is this even possible ?

Comment: You might need to add a trigger to check for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD CONSTRAINT UNIQUE_COLS UNIQUE(NAME, LAST_NAME);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use TRIGGER when inserts new data. the body of trigger will be checking existing data that contains first_name || last_name